# How to use a TS Web Component with separated files in a Webview of VSCode Extension

Tags: typescript, webview, vscode-extensions, web-component

**Context**

I am creating an extension for VSCode. I have created a Web Component to use in a Webview of my extension.
When the web component is in 1 single file, everything works perfectly. For reasons of cleanliness and file size, I have decided to separate the Css from my Web component (And in the future, the html too). That's where the problem starts.

**The problem**

Since it is a CSS file (local resource file), the webview locks the content for security. I have already tried setting `localResourceRoots` and using `webview.asWebviewUri()`. But since the css is inside the webcomponent, instead of the provider panel, I get an "access denied" message.

**The questions**

In short, I have 2 questions.

- Does anyone know how I can load the css in my web component without the WebView blocking the content?
- I'm also going to try to separate the html and load it with a `fetch`. How can I do that without being blocked by the webview?

**My code**

The panel

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { UtilityService } from "../../services/utility.service";

export class QuickviewPanel implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  public static readonly viewType = "pim.quickview";

  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  public resolveWebviewView(
    webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
    context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext<unknown>,
    _token: vscode.CancellationToken
  ): void | Thenable<void> {
    webviewView.webview.options = {
      enableScripts: true,
      localResourceRoots: [this._extensionUri],
    };
    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);
  }

  private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    const webComponentPimPostUri = UtilityService.getWebviewUri(
      webview,
      this._extensionUri,
      ["out", "web-components", "pim-post", "wc-pim-post.js"]
    );
    const cssUri = UtilityService.getWebviewUri(webview, this._extensionUri, [
      "src",
      "web-components",
      "pim-post",
      "wc-pim-post.css",
    ]);
    console.log("cssUri:", cssUri);
    const nonce = UtilityService.getNonce();

    return /*html*/ `<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />      
      <title>Cat Colors</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <pim-post date="2023-12-01" cssUri="${cssUri.fsPath}"></pim-post>
      <script src="${webComponentPimPostUri}"></script>     
    </body>
  </html>`;
  }
  
}
```

The (typescript) web component

```js
class PimPost extends HTMLElement {
  root;
  template;
  css;
  cssUri;
  date: string = "";

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.root = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.cssUri = this.getAttribute("cssUri");
    this.template = this.generateHtml();
    this.css = this.generateStyles();

    this.root.appendChild(this.template);
    this.root.appendChild(this.css);
  }
  //-----------------------------------HOOKS----------------------------
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["date"];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attName: string, oldValue: any, newValue: any) {
    switch (attName) {
      case "date":
        if (newValue) {
          this.date = newValue;
          this.updateDate(newValue);
        }

        break;

      default:
        console.error("Unknown attribute");
        break;
    }
  }
  //----------------------------TEMPLATE----------------------------
  generateHtml() {
    const temp = document.createElement("template");
    temp.innerHTML = /*html*/ `
    <div class="pim-post__main-container">
      <div class="pim-post__text-container">
        <div class="pim-post__text-date" id="pim-post-date"></div>
        <textarea class="pim-post__text-message" id="pim-post-message"></textarea>        
      </div>
      <div class="pim-post__buttons-container">
        <button class="pim-post__buttons pim-post__buttons--first" id="pim-post-btn-delete">X</button>
        <button class="pim-post__buttons pim-post__buttons--last" id="pim-post-btn-edit">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    `;
    return temp.content.cloneNode(true);
  }
  // ----------------------------STYLES-------------------------------
  generateStyles() {
    const styleLink = document.createElement("link");
    styleLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    styleLink.href = `${this.cssUri}`;
    return styleLink.cloneNode(true);
  }

  //-----------------------------FUNCTIONS---------------------------
  updateDate(newValue: string) {
    this.root.querySelector("#pim-post-date")!.innerHTML = `${this.date}`;
  }
}
window.customElements.define("pim-post", PimPost);
```

Comment: Re your recent deleted question, in case it helps: *"I need to retrieve some data from an asynchronous function to use it in my normal synchronous code."* As Quentin said, you can't. That's the take away message from the answers to the questions you've read. Think of it this way: You're standing at your front door, opening it, ordering a pizza by phone, immediately closing the door -- but also expecting to have the pizza when you do. There's no trick or technique that will make something asynchronous happen synchronously. (It's not that it's an unreasonable thing to want, just that it ...

Comment: ... doesn't exist.) Instead, the solution is to embrace the asynchronous nature of what you're doing by extending it to the formerly-synchronous function. Hope that helps some! :-) Happy coding.

Comment: Now, you might be wondering: "Well, why can't I stand there waiting for the pizza before closing the door?" Very reasonable question. The answer is: Because that's not how JavaScript's operating model works. Once a "job" from the job queue (such as running the initial code, or running an event handler) is *started*, it has to be finished before any other code in the same JavaScript global environment can run. This is called "run to completion semantics." So if you're standing there (`while (waitingForTheData) { }`), the code responding to the asynchronous completion can't run, so you'll...

Comment: ...never see that completion. (The pizza analogy falls apart at this point. :-) )